# copying values from one table cell to another also takes background colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

While testing a leader board web-app I noticed that when copying a value from any of the top three cells (coloured gold, silver and bronze respectively) and pasted it anywhere else on the table the value would be pasted with a few pixels of whichever background colour I copied from (The same amount as if you were to select any piece of text here and the size of the blue highlighted box would come with it)

I originally had the cells coloured using JavaScript and I thought this was the problem (shown below 1) so I used CSS instead and took the JavaScript out as below (2).

The table cells are all content editable but I dont see why this would take a small square of colour along with the values.

```
 1:
table.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFFFF"; // White  
table.rows[1].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFD700";   // Gold    
table.rows[2].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";   // Silver
table.rows[3].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "#CD7F32";   // Bronze

2:
tr:nth-child(1)
{
  background-color: #FFD700;
}
tr:nth-child(2)
{
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
tr:nth-child(3)
{
  background-color: #CD7F32;
}
```

I only expected the value to be pasted but the colour is pasted along with it.

Comment: If poss, plz add some html (create a snippet) so we have a working sample. If it doesn't work in a snippet for some reason, tell us.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/16398101/4emfnu1t/ here is a JSFiddle link. An example of the problem I am having is if you click add player then copy the name from the first cell to the newly added one

Comment: Tried chrome and ff and it's not happening for me.